# Use express-jwt as middleware to verify Azure AD issued tokens

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, openid-connect

I would like to know if its possible to use the `express-jwt` NPM package as middleware to verify JWT tokens issued by Azure AD.

We have a web API written in express/node and would like to apply middleware pattern to protect our endpoints and to populate the user principle.

seems like:

```
server.use(jwt({
    audience: '{UUID}',
    issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/{UUID}',
}).unless({path : ['/']}))
```

does not work as it requires a client secret, but from AD (much like in implicit flow) the tokens are retrieved via a user interaction and there is no client secret.

Comment: You can create your own middleware and validate as you want, how do you retrieve the JWT? authorization headers?

Comment: Yeah it's an authorization header (Bearer token)

How would you verify the signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "azure-ad-jwt". Its fairly straight forward and requires no injection into the middleware. You can inject it as an intermediary step in your own "middleware" function of course.

```
 private verifyToken(req: any, res: any) {
        var audience = "xxxxxxxxx";
        var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxx";

        var authorization = req.headers['authorization'];
        return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
            if (authorization) {
                var bearer = authorization.split(" ");
                var jwtToken = bearer[1];
                if (jwtToken) {
                    aad.verify(jwtToken, { audience: audience, tenantId: tenantId }, function (err, result) {
                        if (result) {
                            observer.next(true);
                        } else {
                            res.status(401).send('That is not a valid token!');
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    res.status(401).send('No token in header.');
                }
            } else {
                res.status(401).send('Missing authorization attribute in header.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`express-jwt` supports `multi-tenancy`, which works perfect with azure ad. https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#multi-tenancy

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import jwt from 'express-jwt';

const ISS = 'https://sts.windows.net/********-****-****-****-************/';
const KEYS = {}; // response.body from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
// create another task to refresh KEYS every 24 hours.

app.use('/protected', jwt({
  secret: (req, header, payload, done) => {
    const { kid } = header;
    const { iss } = payload;

    if (iss !== ISS) { // issuer filter
      return done(new Error('invalid token issuer'));
    }

    const key = _.find(KEYS, { kid });
    if (key) {
      const pem = _.get(key, 'x5c[0]');

      if (pem) {
        return done(null, `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${pem}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`);
      }
      return done(new Error('not PEM found'));
    }
    return done(new Error('invalid kid'));
  },
}), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: 'if you can see it, you have a valid access_token.' });
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => { // error handler
  res.status(401).json({ msg: err.message });
});
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims
- https://stevelathrop.net/securing-a-node-js-rest-api-with-azure-ad-jwt-bearer-tokens/